# Java Applet - Moving a ball over the screen

Tags: java, applet

Ok, how to i move from keyboard a ball using an Applet?

I have so far this code, that don't do anything.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class KeyboardGame extends Applet implements KeyListener
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static boolean keyboadrRightPressed = false;

    public void init()
    {
         addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            keyboadrRightPressed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            keyboadrRightPressed = false;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.fillOval(20,20,20,20);
        g.drawString("String :"+keyboadrRightPressed,20,30);
    }

}
```

And also i have to understand how it works. I don't get why my action listener won't work, do i need an

```
while(true)
```

or an Thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action listener might actually be working fine, but you need to repaint the applet when the key is pressed so that your string actually appears. Try changing the keyPressed to this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        keyboadrRightPressed = true;
    }
    else
    {
        keyboadrRightPressed = false;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Actually moving the ball will differ depending on how you want the ball to actually move. I'm guessing you want it to continue moving right while the key is held down, so what I would do is implement a timer or some other form of thread that every .25 seconds (or however long you want) checks the keyboardRightPressed and will move the ball right if it is true. Then in the keyReleased portion of your code you should also add logic to set keyboardRightPressed back to false when you let up on the key.

Comment: i did that, i actually saw that it has a little hold at the beginning, the ball moves 1 pixel and waits 0.5 sec until moves continuously, should i use Threads to solve my problem?

Comment: The pause in there is because of the way keyboard events work. When you think about typing in a text editor, if you press and hold the 'a' key it will type one a, pause for a moment, and then start adding a bunch of a's. So yes, I would use a thread that you can have executing at a consistent interval so you don't get that little lag. You will also want to move the repaint() function call into the thread that is actually moving the ball so that it repaints when the ball is moved and not when the key press is detected.

Comment: OK, i done a lot of things, including the Thread one, but i don't know how to move smoothly the ball over the screen from keyboard, it has that delay ...

Comment: So in keyPressed you have something along the lines of:

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        keyboadrRightPressed = true;
    }
In keyReleased you have something like:
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        keyboadrRightPressed = false;
    }
And in the thread you have something like:
    while (true)
    {
        if (keyboadrRightPressed == true)
        {
             ball.x+=5;
             repaint();
        }
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }
Is that about what you have?

Comment: yes, those are the codes for Main.java http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=265553&c=8441812 and KeyThread.java http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=265557&c=1157960, if you can fix them, i will thank you very much

Comment: Not to shove my coding style down your throat, but this is how I would set it up. When I run this I don't see any real delay. Main.java: 
http://pastebin.com/Mw7MeC0V
KeyThread.java:
http://pastebin.com/8xgCYNqz
Setting it up this way gives a couple advantages, in my opinion. The first being that you only need one thread for all four directions. The other being that you're only calling repaint() in one place and it's when the ball actually changes coordinates.